# Apple SignIn TVOS issue -7014

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, apple-sign-in, asauthorizationcontroller

My team and I have been trying to implement Apple ID Sign in for both iOS and tvOS applications. iOS is able to sign in with Apple ID just fine with the same code, but whenever we tried to sign in through our tvOS app, it gives us the following error:

> [core] Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError
>   Code=-7014 "(null)" UserInfo={AKClientBundleID=[bundleID]}

Here is our code:

```
extension LogInViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate, ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding {

@objc func userDidTapSignInWithAppleButton(){
    let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
    let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
    request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]

    let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
    authorizationController.delegate = self
    authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
    authorizationController.performRequests()
}


//MARK: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate

func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {

}

func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
   print(error)
}


//MARK: ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding

func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
    return view.window!
}
}
```

We have "Sign in With Apple" capabilities Turned on in XCode, and our Identifier for tvOS app is using the same Group App ID as the iOS Identifier so it seems to be fine. There isn't any forums that give this exact error. Can anyone explain what this error code -7104 means, and what can we do to resolve it? Thank you.

Comment: Pierre23 did you find any solution for this? I am facing a similar problem but the error code is 1000 and not 7104. 

I asked the same on Apple forum but no luck https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/424404#424404

Comment: @VijaySanghavi we have the same error. Are you trying on simulator? I think it's an issue with the two identification steps with the simulator. When I tried on a real device it's stopped giving me that error. It even send a notification to my phone but for some reason when I click on it, nothing happens. I'm stuck there...

Comment: Yes! I am trying on the tvOS simulator. I get the two-factor code on my laptop and I am able to successfully sign in in simulator's apple id settings. Have a look at this question posted by me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62370226/is-sign-in-with-apple-siwa-supported-in-the-tvos-simulator

Comment: @VijaySanghavi, how did you solve it? I'm confused. I have the same code as you do.

Comment: I guess the problem is in your two-factor authentication devices. I have not faced any such issues as I have only one device (my official laptop) in which I have logged in with the apple id.

Comment: @pierre23 Could you please tell me what did you do to resolve the problem that nothing happened after click on notification?